# PlayFramework 1.4 prevent propagation after condition not fulfilled

Tags: java, http, playframework-1.x

I have a following problem: I want o use `@Before` to intercept requests and check if a certain condition is fulfilled; if not, prevent propagation and return a message to user.

Is there any other way than throwing an exception?

Code example:

in routes:

```
   GET /someRoute  MainController/someMethod
   GET /otherRoute MainController/otherMethod
```

in Controller

```
public class MainController{
@Before
public static void check(){
// checking, if not fulfilled - render error and requested method is not invoked.
}
public static void someMethod() {/*some action*/}
public static void otherMethod() {/*...other action*/}
```

Comment: Please add some of your code. What did you tried so far?

Comment: Just want to place in Controller `@Before` Adnotation to intercept all requests calling this controller's methods - then i want to check if user has permission to view the result(i get a param from config, it is not important) - if so, called method is invoked (themselves, just like without `@Before`), otherwise i render a error message to page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the method annotated with @Before is on a Controller, you can use all the static function to directly answer. 
For example if you want to return a plain text :

```
public class MainController{
@Before
public static void check(){
  // checking, if not fulfilled - render error and requested method is not invoked.
  renderText("Error");
}
public static void someMethod() {/*some action*/}
public static void otherMethod() {/*...other action*/}
```

That will stop the propagation and send a response to the request.

You can also use error() or forbidden() for example.

Comment: Thx a lot, i wasn't sure if rendering breaking propagation, but you ensured me :)